# In Silverlight Grid, Disable row color change on mouse hover on row?

Tags: silverlight, colors, row

How to disable color change (to gray) when mouse hover on a row of grid?
How to disable color change (to gray) when row is selected by mouse click or keyboard/Enter combination?

I want to keep the originally assigned row color.

Please advice.Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1):

You will need to specify a new template for the `DataGridRow` via a style on the the `RowStyle` property.  Use the existing style for `DataGridRow` found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278066(v=VS.95).aspx).

Remove the `StoryBoard` elements for the "MouseOver", "NormalSelected" and "MouseOverSelected" VisualStates also remove the `DoubleAnimation` for "BackgroundRectangle" from the "UnfocusedSelected" VisualState.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, but instead turned off HitTest so the user couldn't select a row.

It occurred to me that if you don't want the user to know what the selection is, then you don't want a selection.

```
<Style TargetType="data:DataGridRow" x:Key="StyleDataGridRowNoSelection" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseDataGridRowStyle}">
    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```